# Create web page launcher, losing focus

Tags: android, android-intent

I have created a php webpage. I now want to create a launcher application in android phone, it simply opens the browser with the url "http://<mywebsite>/m".

I use uri intent to launch the browser in onCreate function.

```
public void onCreate(...)
{
    ....
    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, new Uri(http://<mywebsite>/m)));
    ...
}
```

I execute this program in my G1 phone (Cyan Mod 5). However, when I click the "Home" key, and then re-enter my application through Task list, I lose focus for my last started browser, and the screen blank

Any suggestion?!
Should I need any code in onResume function to re-focus my web!?

Comment: Sorry I don't really understand the error you are facing. A little bit more detail would help us to answer your question.

Comment: Well it's hard to understand what the OP wants, but I was facing the same issue when the WebView was losing focus, so a login field couldn't be activated by touch, just by using the trackball. Not sure if this relates to the problem, and in what.

Answer (score 0):

If you call `finish()` after `startActivity`, your 'redirect' activity will be closed and removed from the task's activity stack, leaving just the browser activity. For more on the basics, read the [developer guide section on activities and tasks](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html#acttask).